# sequence classification with ready vectors in keras

Tags: classification, sequence, keras

I try to implement a sequence classification.
Each instance is a numpy array of numpy arrays. That is, an array having 60 vectors, each with 50 dimensions. All the instances reside in another numpy array - xx.

I initialize my model as following:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(50,60), return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(xx, yy, epochs=4, batch_size=5)
```

but get the following error:

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (44, 1)

44 is the number of instances.

Where am I wrong?

Note that the vectors are not embeddings of any kind :-) but rather measurements I want to use as features.

Thanks ahead!
Victor.

Comment: LSTMs have a "time" dimension. Keras requires your input shape to be (batch_size, timesteps, features). If you don't have a time component, then you can't use the LSTM, maybe you have to reshape your data? Hard to tell without the actual data.

Comment: I thought that the number of timestamps, in my case 60, are the time dimension... and the batch size is specified in the fit method. Isn't it?

Comment: then you have a flip in the numbers, `input_shape=(60, 50)`. yeah batch size is optional in that case. Regardless, `xx` seems to have a different shape. Can you post that numpy shape please?:)

Comment: XX SHAPE: (44,)

Comment: so where is the rest of your data? :) Shouldn't it be (44, 60, 50)?

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments! Very strange, if I check xx[0] I get an array shaped (60,) and xx[0][0] an array shaped (50,) the data is there. Something is probably wrong with the initialization of the numpy arrays. Do you maybe know what should be the procedure of taking a csv making it ready to feed as vectors into LSTM as a first layer?

Comment: depends how your csv looks like. I usually just read the features as a single 1d vector and then reshape it along the time axis using `_features_.reshape(num_timesteps, -1)`

Comment: each line in my csv consists of 3000 consequent measurements. I want to chunk it into 60 timestamps, each of which will be 50 dimensional vector. Then I want to feed this 50-dimensional vectors, 60 times into an LSTM network, to classify the sequence to 0/1. (I have 56 lines in csv, and do a 5-fold, this is where the 44 come from)